# making a message app but it keep repeating some post

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, message

I am new to xcode.
Recently, I follow some free online tutor to build-up a message app.
I got everything work smoothly. Like I can login, logout, read & write the data from Firebase database.
However, a problem is that the post keep repeat for some time. 
For example, I post six messages - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6  
For the post 1, 2 & 3 will be fine, but the post 4, 5 & 6  will keep repeat as  you can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xheEF.png).

I tried to fix it but with no idea...

The code source is here, https://github.com/RobCanton/SwiftFirebaseTutorials/blob/master/FirebaseApp-9-Refresh-Control-End/FirebaseApp/Home/HomeViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

in `fetchPosts` func, you should check a response post has been contain in current list Post before insert

Comment: So what should I do now... Sorry that I am new to coding.